# PNG images look weird when scaled 50% for Retina

Tags: css, png, sprite-sheet

I have a transparent sprite PNG image - with 50% size for a Retina screen.
The weird thing is my PNG images on regular monitor have those little white line artifacts on them, which are especially visible in Chrome.

Here is a screenshot (it's a bit small, but hope you see it):

[image: original screenshot]

and zoomed to 400%

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Retina screens are not different on size, they are different because of the pixel density.** So making images 50% smaller, won't do the trick. You will need to assign `background-size: 50% 50%` instead.

This will **make your browser render the image but 50% smaller.** Since their size is actually bigger than the displayed size, the remaining pixels will be merged according to the pixel density of your screen.

---

If you are still doing this and the problem persists, then the problem is from the **quality of your image itself.**